# Luminosity distance relation for z around 2? SH0ES Hubble constant

Tags: luminosity

Is there a luminosity distance formula valid for redshift z in range 1-3? Shouldn't this include a term for the current time derivative of the deceleration parameter (q dot)? The only luminosity distance formula I have is for low z, including q0. The SH0ES determination for the Hubble constant presumably includes SNe around z=1. Wouldn't the derivative of the deceleration parameter be significant for SH0ES and relevant for the Hubble crisis? Thank you for your response.